# How to refresh a Page using react-route Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to refresh a page using react-route Link. But the way I have implemented it goes to the URL one step back.(as an example if the URL was ../client/home/register and when I press the reload is goes to ../client/home)

below is my code

```
const AppErrorPage = () => (
    <div>
    <div style={ styles.container }>
        <h2>Error</h2>
        <p> Something went wrong, please reload the page </p>
        <div>
         <Link to="" refresh="true">
            <span>Reload</span>
          </Link>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>  
);
```

Comment: Why do you want to reload the page?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja looking at the example, it looks like an error happens so prompting the user to reload isn't a bad idea.

Comment: @aug I don't think so. Instead of letting user in an error state, asking him for fresh start is fine. But ideally we should overcome such situations without user intervention.

Answer (score 248):

To refresh page you don't need react-router, simple js:

```
window.location.reload();
```

To re-render view in React component, you can just fire update with props/state.

Comment: I actually refactored to use it as a button 
but now i get an error "Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type string"

Comment: `<button type="button" onClick="refreshPage()">
            <span>Reload</span>
          </button>



function refreshPage(){
     window.parent.location = window.parent.location.href;
} `

Comment: You have entered onClick value as string, use this: `onClick={refreshPage}` or `onClick={() => refreshPage()}`

Answer (score 44):

Try like this.

You must give a function as value to `onClick()`

You button:

```
<button type="button" onClick={ refreshPage }> <span>Reload</span> </button>
```

refreshPage function:

```
function refreshPage(){ 
    window.location.reload(); 
}
```

Comment: this is wrong, because function will be called during render. Check comments under my answer

Comment: @LukasLiesis Thank you Just overlooked. Updated it

Answer (score 11):

You can simply run this after successful query.

```
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 9):

I ended up keeping Link and adding the reload to the Link's onClick event with a timeout like this:

```
function refreshPage() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        window.location.reload(false);
    }, 500);
    console.log('page to reload')
}

<Link to={{pathname:"/"}} onClick={refreshPage}>Home</Link>
```

without the timeout, the refresh function would run first

Comment: window.location.reload() is sufficient,for me the page didn't reload when tried window.location.reload(false)

Comment: this one worked as expected for my requirement

Answer (score 6):

You can use this

```
<a onClick={() => {window.location.href="/something"}}>Something</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it using React Bootstrap and a component that you can then drop into any page...

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

export const RefreshCurrentPage = () => {

  function refreshPage(){ 
    window.location.reload(); 
  }

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <Button onClick={ refreshPage } variant="secondary" size="sm" className="btn ml-4">Refresh Page</Button>
    </div>

  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem with `window.location.reload();` is that it does not use client-side rendering. My solution was to do something like this:

```
// Empty.js
export default function Empty() {
    return (<></>);
}
```

```
// App.js
<Route path="refresh" element={<Empty />} />
```

```
// CustomLink.js
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function CustomLink(props) {

    const location = useLocation();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    return (
        <>
            <Link to={props.to} className={props.className} onClick={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (location.pathname === props.to) {
                    navigate('refresh');
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        navigate(props.to);
                    }, 100);
                }
                else {
                    navigate(props.to);
                }
            }}>
                {props.children}
            </Link>
        </>
    );
}
```