# I want my page be refreshed after post request submitted

Tags: reactjs, forms, post, get, page-refresh

i'm creating a comment box with frontend in react; the main component has another one nested and one child.

Here's the main component:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchComments } from '../actions/commentsActions'
import { selectComments } from '../selectors/commentsSelectors'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import { Col, Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Blogs2 from './Blogs2'


const Blogs = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const comments = useSelector(selectComments)

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchComments())
  }, [dispatch])


return (
    <Container>

      <Blogs2 />
  {comments.map(comment=>(
    <Col key={comment._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xk={3} >
        <Message comment={comment} />
    </Col>))}
    </Container>
    )  

  }
export default Blogs
```

This is the nested component where i wrote the post request:

```
import React, { useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Row } from 'react-bootstrap'

const Blogs2 = () => {


    const [author, setAuthor] = useState('');
    const [text, setText] = useState('');
    const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
 

    const client = axios.create({
        baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/comments/" 
      });
  
 
    const addPosts = (author, text) => {
       client
          .post('', {
             author: author,
             text: text,
          })
          .then((response) => {
             setComments([response.data, ...comments]);
          });
       setAuthor('');
       setText('');
    };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
       addPosts(author, text);
      };

  return ( 
   
   
     <Row>
       <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       <input value={author} onChange={(e)=>setAuthor(e.target.value)} />
       <input value={text} onChange={(e)=>setText(e.target.value)} /> 
       <input type='submit' />
       </form>
   </Row>
  
  )
}

export default Blogs2
```

Here's the child component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Row } from 'react-bootstrap'
import './css/Message.css'


const Message = ({comment}) => {
  return (
    <Row id='commenti'>
      <h1>{comment.author}</h1>
      <h1>{comment.text}</h1>
   </Row>
    
  )
}

export default Message
```

All works until that when the form is submitted and the post request done, i need my page to be reloaded in order to my get request be done after that.

Any advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41481658/12541413

Answer (score 0):

If you want your to reload your page completely you can use `window.location.reload();`

or
you can create a function refreshData Blogs component to fetch the comments and pass it as props to Blogs2 component, call refreshData from Blogs2 .

```
 const refreshData = () => {
     dispatch(fetchComments())
    }

<Blogs2 refreshData = {refreshData}/>

const addPosts = (author, text) => {
       client
          .post('', {
             author: author,
             text: text,
          })
          .then((response) => {
             setComments([response.data, ...comments]);
             props.refreshData();
          });
       setAuthor('');
       setText('');
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion Is Just Call Your Get API After Successful POST Request

if you do *window.location.reload* it is reload whole page and after that you will be redirected to top